# Inject CSS locally into remote webpage using WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm, remote-debugging

I want to remote debug a remote webpage and inject my own stylesheet into it locally using WebStorm, so that any changes I make to the CSS are immediately reflected on the page. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with Chrome's Developers Tools. Using `Ctrl + Shift + I`.

There you can edit css-rules and any changes will be reflected on the page immediately.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using WebStorm?

Comment: I think you can't. As `webstorm` can debug `javascript` not `css`... If you need to "debug" `css` you really want to do it via some browser's **developer tools**.

Comment: Fair enough. Then is there a way to list a summary of all CSS edits I have made using Chrome's Developer Tools?

Comment: I would try the following: 1) made any changes 2) copy contents of css-panel to my css-file.